# How can i get Menu item from menu with dataSource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, menuitem

I have menu with XML like this:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuItemCameras" Header="Cameras" ItemsSource="{Binding LocalCameras}" >
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
<MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayName}" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsStreamingVideo}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanStreamVideo}" 
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandSelectLocalCamera, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                    Click="MenuItemCameras_OnClick"/>
</DataTemplate>
</MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

I want to iterate like this:

```
foreach (MenuItem mMenuItem in MenuItemCameras) {
   //some code
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the corresponding `MenuItem`, you can do this

```
foreach (var item in MenuItemCameras.Items) {
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)MenuItemCameras.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    //some code
}
```

But there's a downside, as long as the corresponding `MenuItem` isn't created `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` will return `null`